# Graphql error: "using last without before is not supported"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql, shopify

I am using Gatsby + GraphQL + Shopify. I am having an issue retrieving my orders by the last 10.

My query looks like this:

```
query {
   customer(customerAccessToken: "${customerAccessToken}") {
      orders(last: 10) {...}
   }
}
```

And it returns this:

> "message": "using last without before is not supported"

I noticed this issue happening to some other devs: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Discussion/How-to-get-customer-s-orders-and-sort-by-date-in-descending/m-p/629133/highlight/false#M151241

If you check the docs it says nothing about using `before` with `last`:
[https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/object/order?api[version]=2020-07](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/object/order?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-07)

There is a playground at the bottom where you can test queries.

Anybody else has seen this issue before?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a few moments of playing with the playground ... you can use a **workaround** - `reverse` and `first`

```
{
  orders(first: 10, reverse:true) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        createdAt
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, but `first:10, reverse:true` is not equal to `last:10`, imagine you have 20 data `[1,2,3....17,18,19,20]` The 1st approach will return `[10,9,8,7...3,2,1]` while the 2nd will return `[20,19,18....12,11,10]`.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: It work but without the `sortKey`. The `sortKey` gives an error. You can remove it from there so I can click the check.

Comment: strange ... as it worked in playground embedded in docs

Comment: @xadm Provided the correct answer, if we user "first with reverse" then it will send you the last orders. 
GREAT!!!!

Comment: that is the correct answer